# code does not work with arrays (multiple arrays in arraylist)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

hi I'm having a little problem with arrays.

here's the code:

```
int frame_size = 410;
        int frame_shift = 320;
        ArrayList<double[]> frames = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i + frame_size < inbuf.length; i = i + frame_shift) {
            double[] frame = new double[frame_size];
            System.arraycopy(inbuf, i, frame, 0, frame_size);
            frames.add(frame);
        }
```

here I share a large array into several small, and add them to arraylist

I need to get more of ArrayList arrays and pass them to the function, and then accept the answer and assemble arrays processed one:

```
int[] Cover = new int[frames.size() * nParam];

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {
            double[] finMc = Gos.getVek(frames.get(i));
            for (int c = 0; c < finMc.length; c++) {
                int mc = (int) finMc[c];
                for (int m = 0; m < Cover.length; m++) {
                    Cover[m] = mc;
                }
            }
        }
```

all this code does not work (

all elements of the array are zero Cover.

```
Сover[0] = 0
Cover[1] = 0
Cover[2] = 0
...
```

help solve the problem, please!)

thank you in advance)

**Update**

```
int frame_size = 410;
        int frame_shift = 320;
        ArrayList<double[]> frames = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i + frame_size < inbuf.length; i = i + frame_shift) {
            double[] frame = new double[frame_size];
            System.arraycopy(inbuf, i, frame, 0, frame_size);
            frames.add(frame);
        }

        int[] Cover = new int[frames.size() * nParam];

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {
            double[] finMc = Gos.getVek(frames.get(i));
            for (int c = 0; c < finMc.length; c++) {
                int mc = (int) finMc[c];
                Cover[i * frames.size() + c] = (int) finMc[c];
            }
        }
```

Code^ not work(

**UPDATE 2**

```
double[] inbuf = new double[Size];
        inbuf = toDoubleArray(Gos.data);

        inbuf[2] = 10;
        inbuf[4] = 14;
```

toDoubleArray

```
public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArray) {
    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    double[] doubles = new double[byteArray.length / times];
    for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++) {
        doubles[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * times, times)
                .getDouble();
    }
    return doubles;
}
```

Code not work:

```
int frame_size = 410;
        int frame_shift = 320;
        ArrayList<double[]> frames = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i + frame_size < inbuf.length; i = i + frame_shift) {
            double[] frame = new double[frame_size];
            System.arraycopy(inbuf, i, frame, 0, frame_size);
            frames.add(frame);
        }


        double[] Cover = new double[frames.size() * nParam];

        for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {
            double[] finMc = Gos.getVek(frames.get(i));
            for (int c = 0; c < finMc.length; c++) {
                Cover[i * frames.size() + c] = finMc[c];
            }
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  What does "all this code does not work" mean?

Comment: I wrote all the elements of the array are zero Cover.that is arraylist of why it is not pulled out of the number, apparently..

Comment: Then I just need to use an array Cover, and he still eelemnty zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts spring to mind immediately:

1)
    `for (int m = 0; m < Cover.length; m++) {
        Cover[m] = mc;
    }`

This block starts `m` over at `0` every time through the loop. This means you're always writing over the same portion of the `Cover` array. So effectively, it's only the last frame's data that's stored. You probably meant

```
for(int m = i * frames.size(); m < (i+1)*frames.size(); i++) {
    Cover[m] = mc;
}
```

But this raises a further issue -- you're writing the same value (`mc`) into the entire area allocated for a whole frame of data. You probably want to merge this loop with the previous loop so that this doesn't happen.

```
for (int c = 0; c < finMc.length; c++) {
    Cover[i * frames.size() + c] = (int)finMc[c];
 }
```

2)  `int mc = (int) finMc[c];`

That line casts the value to an `int` which truncates the value stored at `finMc[c]`. If `finMc[c]` is between `0` and `1` this will yield `0` when the data is copied and casted. This is compounded by the previous issue which ensures that only the last frame's data ever gets copied. This is simply solved by removing the cast and declaring Cover as an array of `double`s instead of `int`s.

So in sum, the code might work a bit better if it's written this way:

```
double[] Cover = new double[frames.size() * nParam];

for (int i = 0; i < frames.size(); i++) {
    double[] finMc = Gos.getVek(frames.get(i));
    for (int c = 0; c < finMc.length; c++) {
        Cover[i * frames.size() + c] = finMc[c];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm not very well write the code, do not tell me what to replace it?)

Comment: It's hard to say what the correct fixes are without more information about the problem domain and more context. I'll add my thoughts about what might work to my answer, but take them with a grain of salt.

Comment: I can give you additional information.inbuf array has a length - 1024.frames length - 3.(arrays in it) the length of finMc = 14.

Comment: I mean more about what this piece of code is trying to do. It's hard to infer intent from code, but I've made a guess at it. Does the updated answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes you are right, I want to combine all the arrays in a lossless

Comment: I'll check) Wait a little, please)

Comment: I made a few simplifying edits that make the code a little more clear. It might be helpful.

Comment: I'll check) Thank you!)